# Infinite page loading

Tags: cypress

I try to use cypress to create e2e tests but I hit big hurdle.
While I try to navigate to page section from the header cypress stacks and page is going into infinite loop and finally is not loaded.
Flow is following:

1. Navigate to login page
2. Login
3. Open Home page
4. Select from header different section
5. Try to navigate to new section
   This new section should open in the same window.

I set following parameter:
"modifyObstructiveCode": false,
"chromeWebSecurity": false

Maybe some faced similar issue?

Comment: Any error codes? What the test runner shows? What's your code?

Comment: Cookies lost? https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.